# JMeter - In My local UAT Server same URL request not hitting second time(Error - 500)?

Tags: jmeter

JMeter - Parameterization(using CSV data),
JMeter - In My local UAT Server same URL request not hitting second time(Error- 500)

In My local UAT Server same URL request is not hitting second time it's displaying a Response code like - 500.

I generate script by using blazemeter chrome addons V.1.5.184.
 Kindly give any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to suggest anything without seeing request details, response message, response body, your CSV Data Set Config details and partial CSV file.

Most likely your parameterization doesn't work as expected, I would recommend comparing what's is being sent in 1st and 2nd request using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and double check variables coming from CSV using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler). See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more details on JMeter tests troubleshooting.